# NLTK POS tags extraction, tried key, values but not there yet

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, nltk

I have a list of names on which I am using NLTK to POS tag. I use it along with wordsegment, as the names a jumbled up like `thisisme`.

So I have succesfully POS tagged these names using a loop, however, I am unable to extract the POS tags. The entire exercise is been done from a CSV.

This is what I want the CSV to look like at the end of the day.

```
name,    length, pos
thisisyou 6      NN, ADJ
```

My code so far is

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import wordsegment
from wordsegment import segment
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk.tag.util import str2tuple

def readdata():
    datafileread = pd.read_csv('data.net.lint.csv')
    domain_names = datafileread.DOMAIN[0:5]

    for domain_name in domain_names:
        seg_words = segment(domain_name)
        postagged = nltk.pos_tag(seg_words)
        limit_names = postagged
        for keys,values in postagged:
            print (posttagged)

readdata()
```

And I get this result

```
NN
NN
ADJ
NN
```

This seems OK but it is wrong. Some POS tags should not be on a new line. It should merely be jumbled like `NNNN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` function will insert a newline each time you use it. You need to avoid this. Try it like this:

```
for domain_name in domain_names:
    seg_words = segment(domain_name)
    postagged = nltk.pos_tag(seg_words)
    tags = ", ".join(t for w, t in postagged)
    print(domain_name, LENGTH, tags)
```

The `join()` method returns the POS tags as a single string, separated with `", "`. I've just written `LENGTH` since I have no idea how you got the `6` in your example. Fill in whatever you meant.

PS. You don't need it here, but you can tell `print()` not to add the final newline like this: `print(word, end=" ")`

Comment: Thank alexis, it worked perfectly. I should have asked for help hours ago.

Comment: Could you please explain what happens on (t for w, t in postagged), thanks

Comment: It's a ["generator expression"](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), and passes `join()` the equivalent of a list of strings. See also [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: This particular generator expression throws out the words and keeps the tags. You can examine it like this: `print( list(t for w, t in postagged) )`.

Comment: PS. Since this answer solved your problem, please "accept" it by clicking on the big check mark on the left.